# Why does this not work (glm::make_mat4)?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have this code:

```
glm::mat4 aLookAt(const glm::vec3& Eye, const glm::vec3& Center, const glm::vec3& Up)
{
    glm::vec3 Z = glm::normalize(Eye - Center);
    glm::vec3 Y = Up;
    glm::vec3 X = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Y, Z));
    Y = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Z, X));
    float Matrix[4][4];
    Matrix[0][0] = X.x;
    Matrix[1][0] = X.y;
    Matrix[2][0] = X.z;
    Matrix[3][0] = (float)glm::dot(-X, Eye);
    Matrix[0][1] = Y.x;
    Matrix[1][1] = Y.y;
    Matrix[2][1] = Y.z;
    Matrix[3][1] = (float)glm::dot(-Y, Eye);
    Matrix[0][2] = Z.x;
    Matrix[1][2] = Z.y;
    Matrix[2][2] = Z.z;
    Matrix[3][2] = (float)glm::dot(Z, Eye);
    Matrix[0][3] = 0;
    Matrix[1][3] = 0;
    Matrix[2][3] = 0;
    Matrix[3][3] = 1.0f;

    glm::mat4 theMatrix = glm::make_mat4(Matrix);
    return theMatrix;
}
```

But whenever I try to compile it, it get the following errors:

[image]

Why? This time I actually expected no errors..

Comment: In which line does this error show up?

Comment: Well, the errors disappear when i remove the line `glm::mat4 theMatrix = glm::make_mat4(Matrix);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler tells you why. You are passing `float[4][4]` to a method that expects a `pointer to float`:

```
template<typename T >
detail::tmat4x4< T >    make_mat4 (T const *const ptr)
```

Those types are not compatible. You need a `float[16]` instead:

```
float Matrix[16];
Matrix[0] = X.x;
Matrix[1] = X.y;
Matrix[2] = X.z;
Matrix[3] = (float)glm::dot(-X, Eye);
Matrix[4] = Y.x;
Matrix[5] = Y.y;
Matrix[6] = Y.z;
Matrix[7] = (float)glm::dot(-Y, Eye);
Matrix[8] = Z.x;
Matrix[9] = Z.y;
Matrix[10] = Z.z;
Matrix[11] = (float)glm::dot(Z, Eye);
Matrix[12] = 0;
Matrix[13] = 0;
Matrix[14] = 0;
Matrix[15] = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! But what is there a difference between float[16] and float[4][4] - they are both arrays of the same type and size?

Comment: One is an array of 16 floats, one is an array of 4 arrays of 4 floats. The former will decay to a pointer to float, the latter will decay to a pointer to float[4]. Yes, they have the same size, but they are different types.